# Gerar número sequencial em java

Tags: java

Olá, eu tenho uma classe Aluno com os atributos nome e matrícula. O usuário pode inserir o nome pelo setNome(), mas gostaria de saber como faço pra que a matrícula seja gerada automaticamente (1, 2 , 3, ...)

Comment: Você está salvando num banco de dados?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Não

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria uma classe que vai possuir o valor `static` e que sempre vai te retornar o valor com incremento, exemplo:

### **GeradorMatricula.java**

```
public class GeradorMatricula {
    private static int ID = 1;

    public static int getProximaMatricula() {
        return ID++;
    }
}
```

## Utilizando

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.out.println(GeradorMatricula.getProximaMatricula());
    System.out.println(GeradorMatricula.getProximaMatricula());
}
```

## Saída

> 1
>
> 2

Comment: O `ID` deveria ser inicializado com zero.

Comment: Na verdade não @ramaral, seria necessário zero apenas se eu retornasse `++ID` ao invés de `ID++`.

Comment: Tem razão, peço desculpa, distracção minha.

Comment: @ramaral Estamos aqui pra se ajudar, não se preocupe :)